# Taking an address of an internal array of a temporary object

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clang

I want to make sure I understand correctly the error in the following code example:

```
#include <string>
int main()
{
const char * ptr = std::string("test").c_str();
return 0;
}
```

c_str() member function returns a pointer to the internal array used by std::string to store the string. However, after the semicolon, the temporary created at this line no longer exists and the memory is freed, thus invalidating the pointer. Is this what's happening?

For some reason, when compiling with Visual Studio 2019, the pointer gets assigned a value but points to an empty string while compiling with Clang (through Android's ndk-build) results in a value that also points to the expected string, for a while.

What's going on? Is this simply a case of undefined behavior working differently in two different compilers?

Thanks

Comment: *Is this what's happening?* Yes.  And any use of that pointer besides assigning it a new valid address are going to result in undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no undefined behavior in the code provided.  If `ptr` were dereferenced, then there would be undefined behavior.  (I'm not entirely sure if you can even legally do `if (ptr != nullptr) ...` which doesn't dereference the ptr, but does look at its current *no longer valid* address value.)

Comment: _"Is this simply a case of undefined behavior working differently in two different compilers?"_. Yes.  You should also expect Undefined Behavior to work differently between different compiler _versions_ or different _compilations from the same compiler_ or different _runs of the same binary_.

Comment: @Eljay - Why a dereference is needed here? Logically, after the assignment statement, it no longer holds that ptr points to a memory array that contains a null terminated string "test". It might contain it or it might not, but it is not guaranteed to.

Comment: *Why a dereference is needed here [to get **undefined behavior**]?*  Dereferencing a dangling pointer to a deleted object's internal structures is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: _"... It might contain it or it might not,..."_ - but until the code tries to use the value pointed to (dereference the pointer), there is no Undefined Behaviour.  If the code never dereferences `ptr` then all is ok.  The program can even assign the value of the pointer to another pointer etc.  It's the act of dereferencing which triggers the UB.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line of this discussion is that a dangling pointer is created when the temporary is destroyed at

```
const char * ptr = std::string("test").c_str();
```

and an undefined behavior occurs when dereferencing the pointer.